# Stationarity in time series

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity

If I want to run a regression OLS on financial data $y=\beta x + e$ do I need both the $x$ and $y$ to be stationary or is it fine if just the independent variable is stationary? What is usually done in practice?

Comment: Where is the time index in your model?

Comment: Do you mean $x_{t+1}=\beta{x}_t+\epsilon_{t+1}$?

Comment: I mean $y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+e_t$

Answer (score 0):

In finance many applications call for prediction of future returns based on current or past returns for other vairables. Since these returns are obtained by differentiation all involved variables are stationary.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, no not need to make sure $x$ is stationary before fitting an ARIMA model with $y$. Here is a nice post about fitting ARIMA models with regressors: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

I found the comments useful as well.